# Finding the probability distribution of $Y/X$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$, $Y$ be r.v.s with the uniform distribution on the triangle A = $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}:0 \leq y \leq x \leq 1\}$. 
So $d\mu_{(X,Y)}(x,y)= 2\mathbf{1}_A(x,y)dxdy$.

How do I find the distribution of $Y/X$?

Comment: Have you used [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#Derivation)?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Start by finding the cumulative density function using the fact that
$$
P(Y/X \leq k) = P(Y \leq kX).
$$